# Matlab: Projectle motion

Tags: matlab, projectile

In projectile motion, at any time `t`, the projectile's horizontal (`x`) and vertical (`y`) displacement are:

```
x = v*t*cos(θ)
y = v*t*sin(θ) - 5*t^2
```

where `v` is the initial velocity and `θ` is the initial launch angle.

**Question**:

- A projectile has an initial launch angle of 53° and initial velocity of 10 m/s.
- Make a plot of the displacement coordinates (x,y) between t = 0 and  t = 2s

**My code**:

```
t = [0:0.1:2];
v = 10;
a = 53;
x = v * cos(a)*t;
y = v * sin(a)*t - 5 * (t.^2);
plot (x,y)
```

I want this figure:

[image: target]

But I'm getting this instead:

[image: problem]

**How can I correct this?**

Answer (score 1):

Arguments to the [`sin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sin.html) and [`cos`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cos.html) functions in MATLAB should be in radians, not degrees. You can define `a` as follows to do the conversion from degrees to radians:

```
a = 53*pi/180;
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to convert your angles to radians, you can use the functions [`sind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sind.html) and [`cosd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cosd.html), which accept their arguments in degrees.

Comment: Using the Matlab commands ‘max’ and ‘find’ locate the maximum height it can reach then highlight this point with red stem (using ‘stem’ plot)

Comment: @RamiZakia: I don't understand your comment. Did my answer address the problem you're having?

Comment: it does bro but I need to make a similar as figure 
i need to find the highest point using (find) and (max) commands 
and do other stuff to get figure I want :(

Comment: @RamiZakia: Well, what have you tried? Have you looked at the help for `max`, `find`, or `stem`? We're here to help you solve specific programming problems you may be having, not write code on demand.

Comment: I tried this one
    max(find(x,y)
then I used stem to determine it but it didn't work ...

Comment: @RamiZakia: Try `[~, maxIndex] = max(y); stem(x(maxIndex), y(maxIndex));`.